# SoapUI progmatic - Decompression of response failed

Tags: soapui

I'm trying to run my SoapUI project programatically.

The project runs fine in the SoapUI user interface version: 5.2.1 of OSX

I have a gradle/grails build that gives an exception when trying to decompress the first response:

```
java.io.IOException: Decompression of response failed
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpMethodSupport.getResponseBody(HttpMethodSupport.java:264)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.support.methods.ExtendedGetMethod.getResponseBody(ExtendedGetMethod.java:154)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.BaseHttpResponse.<init>(BaseHttpResponse.java:85)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.SinglePartHttpResponse.<init>(SinglePartHttpResponse.java:44)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.httpRequest(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:81)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpPackagingResponseFilter.afterAbstractHttpResponse(HttpPackagingResponseFilter.java:52)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.afterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:265)
```

build.gradle includes this in dependencies:

```
compile ("com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:5.2.1") {
    exclude module: 'looks'
    exclude module: 'binding'
    exclude module: 'cajo'
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client'
}
```

Code that calls SoapUi:

```
def uploadViaSoapUi() {
    SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner( "SoapUI " + SoapUI.SOAPUI_VERSION
            + " Auto invoice upload" );
    runner.setProjectFile( 'myproject-soapui-project.xml' );
    runner.setEndpoint( 'https://my-server.com' );
    runner.setTestSuite( 'Upload Invoice' );
    runner.setTestCase( 'Good Invoice' );

    runner.run();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure but check for `compression` in preferences of soapui. See here for more information. https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/soapui-interface/preferences-and-settings.html

Comment: Accept compressed responses from hosts - on
Disable decompression of compressed responses - off
Works in user interface but not when called from my code

Comment: Now you may need to show your code excerpt how you are calling the soapui project. In essense, you may need to pass the soapui-settings.xml as well to the program, which has that settings.

Answer (score 3):

Remove UnNecessory dependency from your project build path.

For me, removing below dependency from pom.xml resolved the issue

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeevan. It fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a Groovy step like this in the beginning of the testcase:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI;
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.HttpSettings;


//Change value what is needed for you true or false
boolean enableCompressedResponse = true;
SoapUI.getSettings().setBoolean(HttpSettings.RESPONSE_COMPRESSION, enableCompressedResponse);
```